# GPU device number doesn't match

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, caffe

I am using GPU for Caffe. When I do `nvidia-smi`, it shows

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.63     Driver Version: 352.63         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 750 Ti  Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 44%   52C    P0     2W /  38W |    464MiB /  2047MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro M4000        Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 59%   74C    P0    66W / 120W |   7434MiB /  8191MiB |     95%      Default |


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1428    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             316MiB |
|    0      2200    G   compiz                                         139MiB |
|    1     29863    C   ./caffe-segnet/build/tools/caffe              7413MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I run caffe and choose GPU 1, it will tell me out of memory. If I choose GPU 0 `build/tools/caffe train -gpu 0 -solver solver.prototxt`, it can run.

Why is it?

Comment: CUDA uses its own device enumeration, separate from PCIe, and has a heuristic that assigns device ordinal 0 to the most "capable" device. I do not have time now to quote chapter & verse from the documentation, and hope someone will write a proper answer.

Comment: lets check if your batch size is too high for your 2GB memory.  Due to image dimension and network layer design it might take large memory. Say if you use a image of 600x800 and you have 16 layers of network which have high number of output and kernel size that might not fit within 2GB memory....

Comment: If you are trying run same program running on you `GPU 1` surely it will not fit on `GPU 0`. From your info it takes (**7434MiB** /  8191MiB) around 7GB and your `GPU 0` capable of 1GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nvidia CUDA uses its own device numbering, based on which device is considered the fastest. However, there is also a possibility to obtain a device by its PCI bus ID.

```
cudaError_t cudaDeviceGetByPCIBusId ( int* device, char* pciBusId )
```

It also works the other way around, and you can get the bus ID for a particular device.

```
cudaError_t cudaDeviceGetPCIBusId ( char* pciBusId, int  len, int  device )
```

The Bus IDs would be the values `0000:01:00.0` and `0000:02:00.0` from your table. They are in the format `[domain]:[bus]:[device].[function]`.

See [[1]](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g65f57fb8d0981ca03f6f9b20031c3e5d) and [[2]](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gea264dad3d8c4898e0b82213c0253def).